# Given an IO Request Packet, how can I tell with which function(s) it is associated? E.g IRP_MJ_READ

Tags: windows, driver, wdk, wdm

If I have a fully intact IRP and I am viewing it in a program such as IRP Monitor, how can I tell which function(s) this IRP is associated with, such as IRP_MJ_READ or IRP_MJ_WRITE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IRP` by itself not "associated" with any function. every `IRP` have at least one [*I/O Stack Locations*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/i-o-stack-locations) - and at begin of [`IO_STACK_LOCATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff550659) structure you can view

```
UCHAR                  MajorFunction;
UCHAR                  MinorFunction;
```

> **MajorFunction**
>
> The IRP major function code indicating the type of I/O operation to be performed.

exactly here values `IRP_MJ_XXX`. however complex IRP have multiple stack locations and different locations can have different `MajorFunction`. say IRP which set to filesystem or disk driver initially (in top stacks) have `IRP_MJ_WRITE` (or read). but when disk driver send this irp down to port driver - already `IRP_MJ_SCSI` set in stack

Comment: Ok so it’s not possible to tell exactly which function was used given only a single IRP? Or you could figure it out by determining at which driver the IRP last came from and then examining the IO STACK?

Comment: @the_endian - what you mean under "given  IRP" ? at every time IPR have owner - driver who process this IRP and only he can manipulate with it and access. driver use current stack location (look for `IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation`). you from where have IRP ? anyway you need look for current stack location - `Irp->Tail.Overlay.CurrentStackLocation`

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!